# Schrodinger equation in plain English

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

A mathematician once said that every equation is a sentence that can be expressed in English.

Can you restate Schrodinger's equation solely in English, perhaps for the position and momentum of an electron in a hydrogen atom, identifying what each term stands for along the way?

Here's an example of what we're after:

$$2+2=4$$

"If you take two of anything, or even just the number 2, and add two of the same, you never have to count them to answer the question how many you have, because whenever you do, the answer will always be 4."

Comment: Can you state any French statement in "plain English" as well? Sure, but, things will get lost in translation. Math IS a language.

Comment: @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli You can make up for anything that's lost in translation simply by making the sentence very long, and explaining the individual connotations that each word had in the original sentence. It's possible, but inefficient.

Comment: @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli I should also note that that's not quite what I did in my answer. The process I'm describing is why we have textbooks for these things.

Comment: I don't think a restatement of the Schrodinger equation into English will make the counter intuitive parts of quantum mechanics understandable. It takes more explanation than that. One of the best is Volumne III of the Feynman lectures. http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html

Comment: @Dr. I cannot read your comment as anything other than a recommendation that if my French is weak, I should not ask for an English translation, but remain content with my ignorance. I see no harm in asking.

Comment: @mmesser I have read original papers and commentaries by the architects of QM, including Feynman's 1948 articles, Dirac's Principles of  QM, Heisenberg, Born, etc. Soon I will embark on Schrodinger's 1926 papers because of parts of QM arising from the “amplitudes” of waves in his work. E.g., as sq rts of Probabilities, they would seem to be pure numbers. I am looking for physicist's views of the waves, e.g., whether they “have no physical meaning” (Schrodinger) or they are physically “real” (Born). May one ask here if under Copenhagen there lies an implied neo-Platonism?

Comment: @Willy Bill Williams I would add that I have read one, or relevant portions of one, Bohm's textbook, and did not find it.

Comment: The statement will have to be at least the length of a book, try to explain "quantum mechanics makes me free" using only english metalanguage https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_semantic_metalanguage

Comment: @Willy Billy Williams I was referring to my question, not yours.

Comment: @Wht1FlKnLrnSoKnAnthr yes, I said at least to be on the safe side. Even if you stack all prerequisites college books (math and physics) into one huge book, without using neither equations nor images, your memory will not be able to keep track or make sense of all embedded definitions. You have to "crystallize" these definitions into intuitive concepts first. The "recursion depth" of a language is in principle infinite, but in practice it is very low for humans (about 5 if I am not wrong), due, among other reasons, to limited working memory capacity.

Answer (score 6):

Treating the nonrelativistic case only.

**Time-independent Schrodinger equation:**

$\hat{H}\psi=E\psi$

With math terms allowed:

"The eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian $(\hat{H})$ are the energies $(E)$ of stationary states $(\psi)$."

Without math terms:

"The function responsible for evolving a quantum system in time $(\hat{H})$ has states $(\psi)$ which remain the same up to a constant scaling factor $(E)$ under its action, and the scaling constant is the energy of the respective state."

**Time-dependent Schrodinger equation (for a single particle moving in an electric potential):**

$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi=(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V)\psi$

With math terms allowed:

"Up to various constants $(i\hbar)$, the wavefunction $(\psi)$ satisfies the diffusion equation $(\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi)$ with an extra term $(+V\psi)$ consisting of the potential energy $(V)$ multiplied by the wavefunction."

Without math terms:

"The rate of change $(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})$ of the wavefunction $(\psi)$ at any point is proportional to a measure of its curvature $(\nabla^2\psi)$ at that point multiplied by a constant $(\frac{\hbar^2}{2m})$, added to the potential $(V)$ applied to the system multiplied by the wavefunction itself."

**Time-dependent Schrodinger equation (general):**

$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi=\hat{H}\psi$

With math terms allowed:

"Up to various constants, $(i\hbar)$, the time derivative of the wavefunction $(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi)$ is given by the action of the Hamiltonian $(\hat{H})$ on the wavefunction."

Without math terms:

"The rate of change of the wavefunction at a point $(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi)$ is proportional to the action of the function responsible for evolving a quantum system in time $(\hat{H})$ on the wavefunction."

Comment: Isn't the time-dependent Schrödinger equation a diffusion equation, rather than a wave equation?  it's first-order in time.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Oops, sorry. Edited to correct.

Comment: @probably_someone Can you write the particular equation you are re-stating, and map its math terms to the individual English terms you have used?

Comment: Wouldn't you rather see 2+2=4 than the ridiculous long statement stating it? Sure, maybe the teacher's words help when he's writing the equation on the blackboard, but after first grade (kindergarten) you'd be holding people and all else back by continuing with the long sentences. It's the wrong approach, and that's why we teach the basics first, and then use shortcuts. Anyway, this question has nothing to do with physics, it is about talking about equations. Should be closed.

Comment: @Bob Of course the equations are more powerfully succinct than ordinary language, especially if one has the training to read them. But why the hostility to someone asking who does not? Is this site only for the elite? And censorship of the question? This is my first. It is about physics, as it is about the key equations of physics.

Comment: That's a fair point. It is ok to explain in words. Just that usually the bestway to explain in words is not translating equations to words, biut using words best for what they convey. There is no censorship. But your question was not about explaining physics, it was to translate equations to words. Have you tried asking the same question in the math se? Anyways, I can't censor, only express what I think. If you ask a question about physics you can say no math, but you can't say how they should answer